# change scientific notation to number in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a file .txt like belowe

```
AXN1 6.9e+07 69000000
AXN2 7.2e+07 72000000
AXN2 81000000 81000000
AXN3 1.18e+08 118000000
AXN4 7.7e+07 77000000
AXN9 8e+07 80000000
AXN11 800000 800000
AXN11 2.9e+07 29000000
AXN12 48000001 48000001
AXN18 4.8e+07 48000000
```

I want get that

```
AXN1 69000000 69000000
AXN2 72000000 72000000
AXN2 81000000 81000000
AXN3 118000000 118000000
AXN4 77000000 77000000
AXN9 80000000 80000000
AXN11 800000 800000
AXN11 29000000 29000000
AXN12 48000001 48000001
AXN18 48000000 48000000
```

How can I do it at Linux? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved using `awk` and its `sprintf` function:

```
$ awk '{$2=sprintf( "%d", $2)}1' alegria.txt 
AXN1 69000000 69000000
AXN2 72000000 72000000
AXN2 81000000 81000000
AXN3 118000000 118000000
AXN4 77000000 77000000
AXN9 80000000 80000000
AXN11 800000 800000
AXN11 29000000 29000000
AXN12 48000001 48000001
AXN18 48000000 48000000
```

To save it to file redirect the output to a tmp-file and then move it:

```
$ awk '{$2=sprintf( "%d", $2)}1' alegria.txt > alegria.tmp && mv alegria.tmp alegria.txt && cat alegria.txt
AXN1 69000000 69000000
AXN2 72000000 72000000
AXN2 81000000 81000000
AXN3 118000000 118000000
AXN4 77000000 77000000
AXN9 80000000 80000000
AXN11 800000 800000
AXN11 29000000 29000000
AXN12 48000001 48000001
AXN18 48000000 48000000
```

Comment: Good answer.  Minor variation to catch exponential notation in both numeric columns: cat file.txt | awk '{printf "%s %.0f %.0f\n", $1, $2, $3 }'

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {m,g}awk '( $(NF-!_) = $NF )^_'
> ```

```
AXN1 69000000 69000000
AXN2 72000000 72000000
AXN2 81000000 81000000
AXN3 118000000 118000000
AXN4 77000000 77000000
AXN9 80000000 80000000
AXN11 800000 800000
AXN11 29000000 29000000
AXN12 48000001 48000001
AXN18 48000000 48000000
```